# Grafana Dashboard for Gatling

Tags: performance-testing, grafana, influxdb, gatling, grafana-templating

Is there any grafana dashboard available for gatling. I have gatling version 3.9.0, grafana version 9.2.1 and influx db -1.7.10?

Thanks for the help

I tried using the dashboard available on grafana website but looks like they are all for old version.

Answer (score 0):

try this one: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/9935-grafana-report/
you may also want to have a look at this one
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/gatling-grafana-influxdb